# How to consume websocket apis in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I would like to consume the following [websocket weather api](https://weatherflow.github.io/SmartWeather/api/ws.html).

I tried adapting the [following examples](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) however I am not getting anywhere.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://ws.weatherflow.com/swd/data') as websocket:

        await websocket.send({
          "type":"listen_start",
          "device_id":1110,
          "id":"2098388936"
        })

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(greeting)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

How to consume websocket apis in Python? That is how to get the constant stream of weather information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the api_key parameter is missing:

From the [SmartWeather documentation](https://weatherflow.github.io/SmartWeather/api/):

- Websocket

  - Open a websocket connection
  - `wss://ws.weatherflow.com/swd/data?api_key=20c70eae-e62f-4d3b-b3a4-8586e90f3ac8`
  - Send a JSON message over the websocket connection to start listening for observations from the demo Device. After sending this message your connected websocket client sould receive a new observation JSON message every minute.
  - `{ "type":"listen_start", "device_id":1110, "id":"random-id-12345" }`

I got it working with the following code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://swd.weatherflow.com/swd/data?api_key=20c70eae-e62f-4d3b-b3a4-8586e90f3ac8') as websocket:
        await websocket.send('{"type":"listen_start", "device_id":1110,"id": "2098388936"}')
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(greeting)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Note that according to the documentation, this API key is to get started quickly. Do not use this key in your application.